# Почему при передаче в процедуру или функцию объектa Image возникает ошибка Object Required

Tags: vba, corel-draw

Пишу макрос для CorelDraw 2022. Сделал UserForm, добавил туда картинку (light), написал функцию для смены иконки:

```
Sub ChangePicture(im as Image)
im.Picture = ....
End Sub
```

При вызове ChangePicture light, кидает ошибку, даже если весь код в ChangePicture закомментировать. Объект light существует, проверил кучей дебагов. Также отображается, что у картинки light тип Image.

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: *Чо я не так делаю?* - не показываете код и живой пример. Из опыта - часто проблема находится самостоятельно при подготовке упрощенного примера

Comment: Так буквально это и есть весь код. Объект типа Image создал с помощью встроенного редактора UserForm, передача этого объекта в процедуру вызывает ошибку